# codeigniter installation - location of the system and application folders

Tags: codeigniter, installation, system, directory

fellow codeigniters, I’m moving my local ci site onto a media temple server and I’m having a problem with the location of the system and application folders.

the structure of the server is as follows:

```
../domains   
     /mysite.com  
        /html
```

html is the root of my domain. i.e this is where i’d go when i access www.mysite.com

I placed the ci system folder (ci_system) under domains.

since the html folder is being used by a few ‘under construction’ files, I created a subfolder called ‘mysiteapp’ under html and placed my application folder, idex.php, css, js folders there.

so it looks like this:

```
../domains   
     ci_system
     /mysite.com  
        /html  
           /mysiteapp
              /application
              /css
              /assets
              /js
              index.php
```

I edited the index.php file so that **$system_folder = “../../../ci_system”;**

the problem is, when I access the site, i get a php error:

**Warning: require(../../../ci_system/application/config/constants.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfs/c08/h04/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/ci_system/codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php on line 52**

so it looks like the ci_system folder is being located however CI is still trying to locate the application folder off of the ci_system folder.

I have tried specifying the full path the the application folder but it still tries to concatenate the 2 together.

I have not done many ci installations and my local one was done months ago and i don’t remember it being a pain. so I’m not sure where to look to fix this problem.

hope someone can help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok So the index.php file does have the $application_folder var which can be set and pointed towards the application dir. Could you be kind enough to share the index.php file? You may have to set both up .. i.e the system folder path and the application folder path.

And the only problem I noticed with your system path is that its relative when the CI doc states that you have to use full server paths...

> It is possible to move your application folder to a different location
>   on your server than your system folder. To do so open your main
>   index.php and set a full server path in the $application_folder
>   variable.

```
$application_folder = "/Path/to/your/application";
```

If you do want a quick fix, and have shell access, create a sym link, that should fix it quickly, but its just cutting around the corner.

Comment: hey Designerfoo, I have set $application_folder to many different values including the full absolute path starting with / what happens is that ci keeps concatenating $system_folder with $application_folder. here is an example: $system_folder = "/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/ci_system"; $application_folder = "/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/jugglerapp.com/html/jugglerapp/application"; the error is: Warning: require(/nfs/c08/h04/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/ci_system//nfs/c08/h04/mnt/xxxxxx/domains/jugglerapp.com/html/jugglerapp/application/config/constants.php)... notice the // after ci_system.

Answer (score 0):

What is inside your ci_system directory? Do you see directories like **core**, **database**, **libraries** etc.?
According to your warning message, you have codeigniter in **/domains/ci_system/codeigniter**, or you have wrong settings in your **index.php**.

Comment: Hey shaggy, i was running CI 1.7.2 (which worked fine locally). Since my initial post, I upgraded to 2.0.1 and the problem solved itself. I think the new version of index.php interprets the values of $system_folder and $application_folder differently (the code is different) or it could be something stupid i did. it's working now. for other people who may have similar problem I'm using the full absolute path to each of those 2 folders in index.php. thanks so much for trying to help. cheers.